# Is the Execution Path for a Function invoked inside a Stored Procedure cached?

Tags: t-sql

According to some of my research a benefit of using Stored Procedures over Functions is that they cache an execution path which provides performance benefit due to not having to recalculate it.

So I was wondering if I invoke a Function from within a Stored Procedure is the entire Stored Procedure still cached?

Here's a mocked up example function - it would be used to add further details onto a table selected in the Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnExampleFunction]
(@EmployeeDetails   EMPLOYEEDETAILS READONLY
)
RETURNS @retEmployees TABLE
(AppraisalLevelId INT,
 JobTitleId  INT,
 LocationId INT,
 Name1 nvarchar(200),
 Name2 nvarchar(200),
 Name3 nvarchar(200)
)
AS
     BEGIN
         INSERT INTO @retEmployees
                SELECT 
             ed.*,
              jt.JobTitleName,
              l.LocationName,
              al.AppraisalLevelName
                FROM @EmployeeDetails ed
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN AppraisalLevels al ON al.AppraisalLevelId = ed.AppraisalLevelId
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeDetails m ON m.EmployeeId = ed.ManagerId
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN JobTitles jt ON jt.JobTitleId = ed.JobTitleId
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN Locations l ON l.LocationId = ed.LocationId;
         RETURN;
     END;
GO
```

So the Stored Procedure in psuedo would be used `IF @Condition Return SelectedTable ELSE Return fnExampleFunction(SelectedTable)`

Comment: Please be specific about kind of function you are talking about. Answer might vary.  If you do a search on 'sql server function inside store procedure' you will see some good posts.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide Makes sense that the answer could be different if the function was a recursive CTE compared to a CASE selection or something. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why do you use `multi-statement` table-valued functions instead of `inline` function?  `Multi-statement` function calls are expensive and introduce significant CPU overhead.

Second, the way you want to use it is very strange:

> The Stored Procedure in psuedo would be used IF @Condition **Return**
>   SelectedTable ELSE **Return** fnExampleFunction(SelectedTable)

You just cannot return tables from sp using `Return`.

And now to your main question:

> So I was wondering if I invoke a Function from within a Stored
>   Procedure is the entire Stored Procedure still cached?

Of course stored procedure's plan will be cached.

There is a difference of what is cached when you use `multi-statement` function  (which starts with a  `BEGIN`  and ends with an  `END`  keyword) or `inline` function:

`Multi-statement` functions (table-valued or scalar) have query plans **on their own**. `Inline` functions don't. SQL Server expands and embeds `inline` table-valued functions into the actual queries, similar to regular views, and it optimizes their statements as part of the queries. As a result, there are no separate calls of the function and you don’t have to deal with its associated overhead.

Here is how your `multi-statement` function can be re-written as `inline` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnExampleFunction]
(
    @EmployeeDetails   EMPLOYEEDETAILS READONLY
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    SELECT 
    ed.*,
    jt.JobTitleName,
    l.LocationName,
    al.AppraisalLevelName
    FROM @EmployeeDetails ed
            LEFT OUTER JOIN AppraisalLevels al ON al.AppraisalLevelId = ed.AppraisalLevelId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeDetails m ON m.EmployeeId = ed.ManagerId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN JobTitles jt ON jt.JobTitleId = ed.JobTitleId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Locations l ON l.LocationId = ed.LocationId
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll definitely change it to be inline.

Sorry to confuse you with that first bit - I was writing out the logic I didn't literally mean using a `return` syntax. What I meant in SQL would be `SELECT * FROM SelectedTable ELSE SELECT * FROM  fnExampleFunction(SelectedTable)`